# HTML form redirecting to PHP file when submitted?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an one-page website with a form in it. I am trying to show a "Thank you" message to replace the button "submit" after the form is filled. If that is possible? I want my page to be the same, but with the message, instead of the button.
Also, when I click "submit" the page is redirect to the PHP code, instead of just showing the message I want. Any ideas of what could be wrong?

HTML form:

```html
<form action="envia_fale.php" method="post" id="form_" name="form_">
    <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="text" name="offer" id="offer" placeholder="Offer" required>
    <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "stefanicaguiar1993@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $subject = "OnlyPans.ie form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = "You have received a new offer from " . $full_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['offer'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $full_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['offer'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Email sent. Thank you " . $full_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You want it like the page won't refresh and send the email in PHP then show the thank you message in the HTML? is that right?

Comment: If you want to submit the form without reloading the page (to your PHP code), read up on how to use Ajax. That allows you to submit the data from the form in the "background" (using javascript) and then you can just replace the button with the text you want when you get a response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#form_').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'envia_fale.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                        $('#send').replaceWith("<span>Send successfully</span>");
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form_" name="form_">
        <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="text" name="offer" id="offer" placeholder="Offer" required>
        <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```